# How to use hjust with geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
type<-c("a","b")
y2020<-c(15,10)
y2021<-c(10,15)
DF<-data.frame(type, y2020, y2021)

# Converting to the long format

DF2 <- DF %>% pivot_longer(!type, names_to="year", values_to="number")

#Calculating the difference between 2021 and 2020 value
DF2 <- DF2 %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(diff=number[match('y2021',year)]-number[match('y2020',year)]) %>% ungroup()
```

And I am trying to build a graph like this one - https://postimg.cc/hfPytBST

```
ggplot(DF2)+geom_path(aes(number, type))+geom_text(aes(number, type, label=year))
```

How do I use hjust to adjust labels here so they don't overlap with the geom_path? Previously I've already built such graph where all the values decreased over the time period, so I used `ifelse(year=="y2021", 1.4, -0.5)` since all the labels for each year had to be moved in one direction, but this solution doesn't work here. I came up with calculating the difference between 2021 and 2020 and using it in a conditional like `if(diff>0){}`, but that didn't get me very far.

I would appreciate any help! Sorry if the question is a bit vague, I'm new to R and just joined Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `ggrepel` ?

```r
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(DF2,aes(number,type)) +
    geom_path() +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=year))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, now I know what ggrepel does! :) but I'm trying to reproduce a specific graph like this one that I've done before - https://postimg.cc/hfPytBST